# How to get jsp text field data into java file?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

Hello I am trying to get value of text field in other java file.  I am trying following code.

```
 <aui:form action="<%=editpollURL.toString() %>" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
  method="post" >
 <aui:input name="title" label="title"/>
 <aui:input type="textarea" name="pollquestion" rows="5" cols="25" label="Poll   
 Question" />
```

following is my java code.

```
String title = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "title");
String pollquestion = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "pollquestion");

System.out.println("Your inputs ==> " + title + ", " + pollquestion);
```

I cant write user input from jsp file.. Kindly help me.

Comment: can you check if this works if you delete the 'enctype="multipart/form-data"'  attribute ?

Comment: remove enctype="multipart/form-data" from form..i guess i would work

Comment: @yannicuLar. how to upload photo into database? and how to retrive photo from database. i am try to upload photo from jsp file. that should be store in database and that photo i want to display in another form. how to do this please tell me easy way

Comment: @LuckyBoy hello how to upload photo in jsp file from our computer using liferay? i have one upload.jsp file from that i want to upload photo,in java file i want to write my logic and i want to show my photo in display.jsp. that photo store in database also. kindly help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, you should work with a UploadPortletRequest  like that:

```
public void yourAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
        throws PortletException, IOException {


    UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(request);
    String filePath = uploadRequest.getFileName("filePath");

    try{
        java.io.File file = uploadRequest.getFile("filePath");
    //Manage the Upload

    }catch (Exception e) {
        ///
    }

}
```

Your jsp input could be like :

```
<aui:input type="file" label="upload your file"  name="filePath" />
```

make sure to use a matching "name" attribute, and use 'type="file"'

Comment: then how to retrieve in other jsp file?

Comment: retrieve what ? IS there another jsp ? plz explain it a bit better

Comment: yes. i have 2 jsp page. from upload.jsp i m tring to upload my photo and display .jsp file i want to display that photo

Comment: have you succeeded uploading to the database ? You'll need to post much more info about your database, to get that answer. You better open another question for this

Comment: should i give my service.xml file here?

Comment: You're using Service Builder ? You should really start another question about this. I'll make sure to check it and try to help

Comment: hello @yannicular i have post my question "how to upload photo in database and how to retrive in jsp page"

Comment: yannicular.. kindly check this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060659/how-to-upload-photo-in-database-and-how-to-retrive-in-jsp-page"