# how to upload photo in database and how to retrive in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I'm providing my `service.xml` file which contains the table details:

```
<entity name="Testimonial" local-service="true" remote-service="false">
    <!-- PK fields -->
    <column name="TestimonialId" type="long" primary="true" />

    <!-- UI fields -->
    <column name="subject" type="String" />
    <column name="area" type="String" />
    <column name="username" type="String" />
    <column name="email" type="String" />
    <column name="photo" type="String"/>
    <column name="company" type="String" />
    <column name="designation" type="String" />

    <!-- Audit fields -->
    <column name="createdAt" type="Date" />
```

Here is my java file where I have written the logic of storing data in database:

```
public void updateTesti(ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException
{
    String subject = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"subject");
    String area = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"area");
    String username = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"username");
    String email = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"email");
    String company = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"company");
    String designation = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"designation");

    System.out.println("Your inputs ==> " + subject + ", " + area + "," 
    + username + "," + email + "," + company + "," + designation);

    Testimonial T1 = new TestimonialImpl();

    // set primary key
    long TestimonialId = 0L;
    try {
        TestimonialId =
        CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(
        this.getClass().getName());
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    T1.setTestimonialId(TestimonialId);

    UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = 

    PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);
    String filePath = uploadRequest.getFileName("filePath");

    try{
        java.io.File file = uploadRequest.getFile("filePath");
        //Manage the Upload

    }catch (Exception e) {
        ///
    }
    // set UI fields
    T1.setSubject(subject);
    T1.setArea(area);
    T1.setUsername(username);
    T1.setEmail(email);
    T1.setCompany(company);
    T1.setDesignation(designation);
    T1.setPhoto(filePath);

    // set audit field(s)
    T1.setCreatedAt(new Date());

    // insert the book using persistence api
    try {
        TestimonialLocalServiceUtil.addTestimonial(T1);
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Tell me where am I wrong and what is missing?

Here is my JSP code:

```jsp
<aui:form name="fm" method="POST" action="<%= updateTestiURL.toString() %>">
    <aui:input name="subject" label="Subject"/>
    <aui:input type="textarea" name="area" label="your Testimonial" />

    <aui:input name="username" label="Username"/>
    <aui:input name="email" label="Email"/>
    <aui:input type="file" label="upload your file"  name="filePath" />
    <aui:input name="company" label="Company"/>
    <aui:input name="designation" label="Designation"/>

    <aui:button type="submit" value="Save"/>
```

Comment: You are trying to set value of the 'photo' , which is a String attribute, with a java.io.File Object.  Did you mean to save the image's path, or a  byteArray of the File ?

Comment: i want to store image path into database

Comment: how it is possible tell me please

Comment: shakedown. kindly help me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to store the image's Path. Even if you had them uploaded from one and only computer, and you could access that path and work with full paths, which is probably not your case.

Since you can get a java.io.File, you can retrieve an InputStream, and work with bytes[] and store them either as Text/String or something equivalent to a Blob.

You can check in Liferay's source for ImageLocalServiceImpl class and see how it's working with these resources

Edit : a hint to get InputStream

```
            InputStream str = (InputStream)uploadRequest.getFileAsStream("filePath", false);
```

Comment: i m tring to devlop webpage that will run on many system and photo should be upload from any where. how to do this? kindly help me

Comment: In other words, you will open the File's stream and store it's bytes as a stream in your database. You can use the functions in ImageLocalServiceImpl to store the inputStream to bytes and vice versa

Comment: where exactly are you having problems, storing a byte array to the equivalent table column ? We'll have to take a look to your updated code and error logs

Answer (score 0):

can accomplish this task using servlet...
 this is my form.jsp file

```
html>
<body>  
        <form id="staff_feedbackform"  method="post" action="uploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="register">
        Select Photo:<input type="file" name="photo">
        <p><label> NAME:</label><input type="text"  name="name" /></p>
        <p><label>EMPLOYEE ID:</label><input type="text" name="id"/></p>
        <p><label>E-MAIL ID:</label><input type="email" name="email"></p>
        <p><label><input id="gobutton" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="submit" />  </label></p>
        </form>
</body>
```

This is my servlet file

```
  @WebServlet("/FileUploadDBServlet")
  @MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 10177215) // upload file's size up to 16MB
  public class FileUploadDBServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;   
   /**
   * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
    */
public FileUploadDBServlet() {
    super();
}
private final String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
private final String dbUser = "root";
private final String dbPass = "";
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        String id=request.getParameter("id");
        String email=request.getParameter("email");        
        InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file        
        // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
        Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");
    if (filePart != null) {
        // prints out some information for debugging
        System.out.println(filePart.getName());
        System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
        System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());             
        // obtains input stream of the upload file
        inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
    }        
    Connection conn = null; // connection to the database
    String message = null;  // message will be sent back to client        
    try {
        // connects to the database
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);  
        conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbUser,dbPass);
        // constructs SQL statement
        Statement st=conn.createStatement();   
        String sql = "INSERT INTO file1(id,name,email,photo) values (?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1,id);
         statement.setString(2,name );
          statement.setString(3,email );

        if (inputStream != null) {
            // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
            statement.setBlob(4, inputStream);
        } 
        // sends the statement to the database server
        int row = statement.executeUpdate();
        if (row > 0) {
            message = "File uploaded and saved into database";
            out.println("uploades succesfully");
            System.out.println("uploades succesfully");
        }            
    }        
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);           
        message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

Table structure for table file1

```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `file1`;
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `file1` (
   `id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `photo` longblob NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and this is my servlet mapping code include web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.servlet.FileUploadDBServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/uploadServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

this is retrieving part of image  and this is my show_image.jsp

```
<%
String id="1250";
session.setAttribute("num", id);
%>
  <body>
  <image src="display.jsp" border="0" height="200px" width="200px" alt="NO PIC"/>
  </body>
```

and here i am externally referencing image through dispaly.jsp file

```
  <% Blob image = null;
 String no=(String)session.getAttribute("num"); 
 byte[ ] imgData = null ;
 Statement stmt = null;
 ResultSet rs = null;
 try {
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 Connection con = (Connection);         DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","");
 stmt = con.createStatement();
 rs = stmt.executeQuery("select photo from file1 where id = '"+no+"'");
 if (rs.next()) {
 image = rs.getBlob(1);
 imgData = image.getBytes(1,(int)image.length());
 } else {
        out.println("Display Blob Example");
        out.println("image not found for given id");
        return;
        }
  // display the image
 response.setContentType("image/gif");
 OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
  o.write(imgData);
 o.flush();
  o.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
                       out.println("Unable To Display image");
                       out.println("Image Display Error=" + e.getMessage());
                       return;
                      } finally {
                                try {
                                     rs.close();
                                     stmt.close();
                                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                                                             System.out.println(e);
                                                             e.printStackTrace();
                                                             }
                      }
    %>
```